# How do I bind an empty string instead of a zero for an int field in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm using the code below to bind the content that comes from the list to the view.
It's a list of person objects. This person object has one numeric field(year).
Sometimes the content of the year field in the db is zero.
When that happens it is binding zero on the input field of the form.
Instead I would like to bind an empty string.
That is, just leave the field blank instead of showing the number zero.
How do I do that?
Obviously, when there is an actual year it should keep displaying the year.

Model

```
@Entity
public class Person implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String name;

    private int year;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

}
```

DTO

```
public class PersonList {
    
    private List<Person> personList;

    public List<Person> getPersonList() {
        return personList;
    }

    public void setPersonList(List<Person> personList) {
        this.personList = personList;
    }

}
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/person", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView editPerson(@ModelAttribute PersonList personList)
{
    //perform operations

    //display results
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("Person.html");
    modelAndView.addObject("personListBind", personList);
        
    return modelAndView;

}
```

View

```
<form action="person" method="post" th:object="${personListBind}">
<th:block th:each="person, itemStat : *{personList}">

    Name:
    <input type="text" th:field="*{personList[__${itemStat.index}__].name}" />

    Year:   
    <input type="text" th:field="*{personList[__${itemStat.index}__].year}" />
</th:block>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use *derived value* methods, so the UI sees the field as a string.

*Model*

```java
@Entity
public class Person implements Serializable {

    // all members from question are here, including getYear() and setYear()

    @Transient // Not a database column
    public String getYearStr() {
        return (year == 0 ? "" : Integer.toString(year));
    }

    public void setYearStr(String yearStr) {
        this.year = (yearStr.isEmpty() ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(yearStr));
    }

}
```

*View*

```thymeleaf
    Year:
    <input type="text" th:field="*{personList[__${itemStat.index}__].yearStr}" />
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you. Couple questions. 1) Which of the available Transient should be used? I opted for org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient and it worked well. In fact, even removing Transient it worked well and didn't create a db field. So why it's needed? 2) How does the view knows which field to call if yearStr is not there? Yes, there is getYearStr but not yearStr like in the view. So not sure how the mapping occurs. For the other fields there is something like private String name. Then the view uses "name". So it matches.

Comment: @jkfe No, `name` and `year` does not access the *fields* by those names. A *getter* method named `getName()` implies a *property* named `name`. A `setter` method named `setName()` implies that the property is updatable. That's why `getYearStr()` makes Thymeleaf see a property named `yearStr`. The *fields* are `private` cannot be seen by Thymeleaf.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the explanation. Sure, private. Forgot about that. What about transient?

Answer (score -1):

Something along these lines should work for you if I understand correctly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<input type="text" th:if="${year eq 0}" value="No year">
<input type="text" th:unless="${year eq 0}" th:value="${year}">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How does that make the POST handling work *(see Controller `editPerson` method)*?

Comment: Looks like I misunderstood what he was trying to do completely. Your solution looks good I think.

Comment: theChoosyBeggar I tried this, but did not work to display empty field. But looks promissing. Would like to learn about this if and unless in thymeleaf. Maybe I did something wrong. Can you clarify? I see Andreas mentioned the issue with POST. Would like to try to get to that. Maybe doing a requestparam and converting on the controller would work.

Comment: Using this thymeleaf condition idea I could make it correctly display blank when year is zero and show the year when there is one. This is the code: <input type="text" th:value="*{personList[__${itemStat.index}__].year==0} ? '' : *{personList[__${itemStat.index}__].year}">. The problem is that when I edit the field and click save and then check the value in the controller, it continues to be zero. Guess that's what andreas was refering to as the POST issue. No way to solve that?